# Setting variables in if statement using JavaScript throw error (already declared)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have this code

```
if (found === true && premium === 'active' || premium === 'trialing') {
  var free = false
} else {
  var free = true
}
```

The express server works fine on both localhost and remotely on Heroku, I tried deploying this app to firebase hosting, one the error that prevented me to deploy is

> 75:17  error    'free' is already defined no-redeclare

I am not sure how to fix that, my goal is simply to pass `free` variable with a response like so

```
response.render('master.html', { links, profile, free })
```

Comment: have you tried putting `var free` before the `if`, and inside (`if` and `else`) just the assignation without `var` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can **declare** this way  and remove the **else condition**

```
let free = true;
if (found === true && premium === 'active' || premium === 'trialing') {
   free = false 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-redeclare

```
var free = true;
if (found === true && premium === 'active' || premium === 'trialing') {
  free = false
}
```

Comment: Thanks! the idea is there but I believe to either use global let or set variable like `free = true`